# How to get value from property in BeanShell (jmeter)

Tags: variables, jmeter, beanshell

I have got several thread groups. I want to use variable from the first group. In second group this var should be used in BeanShell.
So: in first thread group I created BeanShell Assertion with this code:

```
 ${__setProperty(erroriden, ${erroriden1})};
```

In second thread group I have BeanShell pre-processor. 
If has line like this:

```
String[] erroriden = (vars.get("erroriden")).split(",");
```

I tried some variations like this:

```
String[] erroriden = (vars.get("__property(erroriden)")).split(",");
String[] erroriden = (vars.get("${__property(erroriden)}")).split(",");
```

but it doesn't work. 
Please help to use ${__property(erroriden)} in BeanShell pre-processor.

Comment: Do you get any errors? I what way "doesn't it work"?

Comment: Hm, seems that structure `String[] erroriden = (vars.get("${__property(erroriden)}")).split(",");` works ok. Log says: `2015/06/23 16:33:25 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Random;  String[] erroriden = (vars.get("6618291,2072106868,601 . . . '' : Typed variable declaration `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first Thread Group:

```
props.put("erroriden", vars.get("erroriden1"));
```

In the second Thread Group:

```
String[] erroriden = props.get("erroriden").split(",");
```

- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) scope is limited to the current thread group only
- JMeter Properties are usual [Java Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) which are global for JVM instance
- See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter.

Comment: Thank You, Dmitri. You helped me for the third time!

Comment: I want to clarify, could this method be used to the massive amount of data, like thousent of Ids?

Comment: Yes as long as it fits in JVM Heap. However if this code is used by many threads and amount of data is really "massive" I would recommend switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy as a language as Beanshell has some performance limitations. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for benchmarks and details on groovy scripting engine installation