# Choosing id one by one from a variable in jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter, beanshell

I want to delete mappings in DB using DataService.
For this purpose

1. I run search query for all ids in first thread group.
2. Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002558/how-to-get-value-from-property-in-beanshell-jmeter) I put my Ids into the property.
   Now property has view like that `b69243ee6e9efdf66114200dc93881ac,b69243ee6e9efdf66114200dc90f5ba4,b69243ee6e9efdf66114200dc90e2184`
3. I want to all delete mapping using this Ids from property one by one.
   For this purpose I need run BeanShell Pre-Processor and choose first id and put it into variable. Please, help me with this script.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) is the solution. But in my experience, I use regular expression extractor to grab the values and put it in one variable then loop it using ForEach Controller. I think these step will help you:

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor to grab the ids.
   Make sure you fill field "Match No" with negative number (i.e. -1). Put the extracted value into one variable (i.e. **IdVar**. Fill **Reference Name** with **IdVar**). This step will grab all matched ids and put it into **IdVar** variable.
2. Then Add ForEach Controller to process each ids from **IdVar** variable.

For the details, just download this [sample](http://jmeter.apache.org/demos/ForEachTest2.jmx) and try to run it.

I hope this will help you. :-)